# Why do I get bizzarre results when I override methods?

Tags: javascript, overriding

**tl;dr**: I believed that in the general case doing this:

```
// My code
var wtf = Some_Class.prototype.someMethod
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    wtf.call(this, parameters)
}
```

should be equivalent to doing nothing. I've found out that it is, however, not the case. Where was I wrong?

Somebody's code has a method I'm interested in:

```
// Somebody's code
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    // function body
}
```

I'd like to override this method. I always thought that the JavaScript method of doing this is like that:

```
// My code
var wtf = Some_Class.prototype.someMethod
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    wtf.call(this, parameters)
    // My stuff
}
```

I've seen such a code a few times already and it usually seemed to be working.

Not in this case, however. Even if my overriden function contains nothing but a call to base:

```
// My code
var wtf = Some_Class.prototype.someMethod
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    wtf.call(this, parameters)
}
```

I suppose in this case my code should in no way affect the program's behavior, right? Wrong. I get bizzarre results whenever this method is called. Commenting out the above code fixes all problems.

This must be some known pitfall in JS... What is the correct JS way to override methods and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Object Inheritance

Firstly, be sure that you have correctly extended the first object's prototype, otherwise you may not have access to parent functionality relying on the 'this' keyword.

```
ExtendedThing.prototype = Object.create(Thing.prototype);
```

Using 'apply', rather than 'call' allows the original arguments to be passed through without declaring them. I'd recommend doing this unless you know exactly how the overridden method is designed to work.

```
ExtendedThing.prototype.do = function ()
{
    return Thing.prototype.do.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

I've created a little jsfiddle that should be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/z2yeuytw/4/

### Method Overwriting

A developer may choose to make their implementation read-only by calling Object.freeze(Thing), making this impossible but I've created another fiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/b1exeaL6/3/

```
(function () {
    const oldDo = Thing.prototype.do;
    Thing.prototype.do = function () {
       return oldDo.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

#### Namespace Pollution

It is advisable to copy the old method inside an iffy (or use scoping) to avoid this method being overwritten again by mistake.

### Do you trust the original object?

```
function Thing() {
   var tmp = Thing.prototype.do;
   this.do = function() {
     tmp.call(this);
     //do some weird stuff.
   };
}
```

The code above would be pretty odd but it would quietly scupper any overwrite.

Comment: Must I create a new class? Hardly appropriate, since my goal is to modify the behavior of the existing class rather than to create and use a derived class :(

Comment: Aha! I see. My apologies, I understood "override" in the OOP sense. I have updated the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/b1exeaL6/3/

The only things I can really add are:
1. Doing the overwrite in an iffy so as not to pollute the document namespace
2. Be aware that the original developer can use Object.freeze(Thing) to prevent overwriting.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the original object may overwrite your version of the method. See: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/1fugz14o/1/

Comment: Found the reason. Nevertheless many thanks for a throrough explanation of the problem.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed that I didn't spot that. It's a classic reason!

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT What an ubelievably, ununderstandably stupid mistake on my part.

I was typing:

```
// My code
var wtf = Some_Class.prototype.someMethod
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    wtf.call(this, parameters)
}
```

While I should OBVIOUSLY be typing:

```
// My code
var wtf = Some_Class.prototype.someMethod
Some_Class.prototype.someMethod = function(parameters) {
    return wtf.call(this, parameters)
}
```

This can probably only be explained by my current state of utmost sleepiness and loopiness. No wonder I was getting bizzarre behavior if the caller was not getting returned values.

Sorry guys for this.